# Mergylan's Theorem: Lemma Question in Carleson's Proof

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Taken from pg 5 of: http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/10741/8762
[image]

In the lines following the author mentions that $$\iint_{|z|<R}dx dy \int_{\partial \omega}\frac{|d\mu(\zeta)|}{|z-\zeta|}<\infty$$

I'm having trouble seeing why this is so. What if the measure has point mass on a point on the boundary, couldn't this quantity then blow up?

Comment: It can blow up in places. But it's a locally integrable function. Because the kernel is  locally integrable. And Fubuni.

Comment: With respect to the dirac-delta measure at z is it locally integrable?

Comment: I mean with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Integrate against it first (Tonelli's theorem allows you to). You'll get a bounded function to be integrated against $\mu$.